# Android Studio: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Вот такая ошибка в строке `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 24.0.0, 23.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0

[image: Несоответствие версий]

Чтобы посмотреть версии библиотек, я использовал это:

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

Результат:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations

------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:0.9.5
|    +--- com.mikepenz.iconics:library:0.7.3
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3 -> 23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)

|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.2.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)

|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1
|         |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.
1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:10.2.1
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)

|              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:10.2.1
|              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.
1 (*)
|              |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1 (*)
|              +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1 (*)
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:10.2.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common:10.2.1
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:10.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:10.2.1 (*)
+--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.1
|    +--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.5.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|    \--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.5.1
|         +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|         +--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1
|         |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|         |    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|         |    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 2
4.0.0
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)

|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:design:23.4.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:9.4.0
|              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 ->
10.2.1 (*)
|              |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0
 -> 10.2.1 (*)
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 -> 10.2.
1 (*)
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 -> 1
0.2.1 (*)
+--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.0 -> 10.2.1 (*)
\--- com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1


    (*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Мой build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.datingservice"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:0.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.5.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

***Вопрос:***
Что следует изменить в коде, чтобы пропал конфликт библиотек?

Comment: У вас конфликт версий включенных в сторонние библиотеки библиотек поддержки. Добавьте строку `exclude group: 'com.android.support'` аналогично как это сделано для testCompile к каждой библиотеке, где в выводе вашего запроса есть ` версия1 -> версия2`. Эта строка исключит библиотеку поддержки из внешней библиотеки. Так же и для других конфликтов. Или исправьте подключенные версии библиотек поддержки на 24.0.0. А что support-библиотеки такие старые используете?

Comment: @pavlofff Огромное спасибо! Всё решилось. Заодно обновил библиотеки, как вы посоветовали. Отправьте это как ответ, для подтверждения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff)

> У вас конфликт версий включенных в сторонние библиотеки библиотек
>   поддержки. Добавьте строку exclude group: 'com.android.support'
>   аналогично как это сделано для testCompile к каждой библиотеке, где в
>   выводе вашего запроса есть `версия1 -> версия2`. Эта строка исключит
>   библиотеку поддержки из внешней библиотеки. Так же и для других
>   конфликтов. Или исправьте подключенные версии библиотек поддержки на
>   24.0.0. А что support-библиотеки такие старые используете?

Comment: Помогите, похожая проблема:

...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: @Hinc, а в чём проблема? Опишите подробнее.