# Проблема при обновлении версии com.android.support:appcompat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle

При попытке повысить версию `com.android.support:appcompat` до версии `27` получил следующую ошибку:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.0, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В следствие чего я не могу выполнить сборку проекта. Как исправить?

**upd**

```
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |              |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*
)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
\--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)

debugCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for 'debug' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugImplementation - Implementation only dependencies for 'debug' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugMetadataElements - Metadata elements for debug (n)
No dependencies

debugProvided - Provided dependencies for 'debug' sources (deprecated: use 'debugCompileOnly' instead)
. (n)
No dependencies

debugRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: debug
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |              |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*
)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
\--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
     +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
     \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)

debugRuntimeElements - Runtime elements for debug (n)
No dependencies

debugRuntimeOnly - Runtime only dependencies for 'debug' sources. (n)
No dependencies

debugUnitTestAnnotationProcessorClasspath - Resolved configuration for annotation-processor for varian
t: debugUnitTest
No dependencies

debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: debugUnitTest
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |              |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*
)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: debugUnitTest
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.2.0 -> 27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|         |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|         |    |              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|         |    |              |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|         |    |              \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|         |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*
)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1
|         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[11.0.4] -> 11.0.4 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1 (*)
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

Comment: Текст ошибки понятен?

Comment: @Эникейщик Понятен. Ввел  `com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0` появилась новая ошибка где вместо `com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0` стоит `com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0` Отсюда вытекает новый вопрос: как обновить все и сразу?

Comment: А фиг его знает. Пару строчек можно и вручную обновить.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668185/android-studio-all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-versio

Comment: @Эникейщик а ну да и еще,блин, при попытке обновления  `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.1'`  получаю ошибку: `Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v7:27.1.1`

Comment: добавьте вывод `gradlew -q app:dependencies`

Comment: @DeKaNszn добавил в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас все support-библиотеки версии 27.1.1, кроме одной: `com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0`

добавьте в dependencies `com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1`

так же вы можете убрать прямую зависимость `com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1` (она подтягивается автоматически библиотекой `support-v4`)

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо