# В файле build.gradle подчёркивает красным зависимости com.android.support. Как исправить?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle

Вот содержимое моего файла грейдл:

```xml
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias ***
            keyPassword ***
            storeFile file('***')
            storePassword '***'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.frienddime.frienddime"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 146
        versionName "2.03.00 Chop-Chop "
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation "com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0"
    implementation "com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0"
    implementation "tech.gusavila92:java-android-websocket-client:1.1.4"
    apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
    implementation "com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.24.0"
}
```

Раньше этот проект делался на второй версии андроид студии и всё было норм. После установки третьей студии я обновил в проекте версию грейдл и версию sdk. Раньше sdk 24 была вроде, а теперь 27. И соответственно пришлось обновить и библиотеки com.android.support.

Но почему-то их подчёркивает красным. Причём подчёркивает только одну строку, но если её удалить то тогда подчёркивает следующую, и так пока я не удалю все строки с com.android.support.

Если навести на строку то говорит что надо использовать библиотеки com.android.support одной версии и якобы у меня имеется зависимость com.android.support другой версии. Но в этом файле больше нет зависимостей этой библиотеки другой версии, все версии одинаковы.

Ещё была странная проблема, при компиляции грейдл писал что надо заменить compile на implementation, хотя я это сделал и нигде не было compile, но после обновления студии это сообщение перестало высвечиваться.

Проект работает и с этой ошибкой, но возможно из-за этого в одном из файлов у меня перестал работать import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat; и пришлось его заменить на import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

Comment: Что выдает ``gradlew -q app:dependencies``?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема при обновлении версии com.android.support:appcompat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818647/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-com-android-supportappcompat)

Comment: А где это написать?

Comment: В Андроид Студии внизу есть окошко Terminal. В него.

Comment: @Эникейщик Что-то там очень много всего вывело